# The <html> element not fit the screen

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple, responsive layout, and I have a problem with the unexpected size of html element. Everything is fine when the size of a screen is greater than 1080px, but everytime I resize the screen or load the page at a mobile, the html element becomes smaller than the screen width.

[Here you can see what I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVxZ3.png)

[And here you can see the html width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVcy6.png)

What I've tried:
(I am using [this](https://github.com/jannec22/HTML/blob/master/reset.css) css reset)

1) setting the html and body margin, padding, to 0 and width of them both to 100%;

2) setting the box-sizing property to border-box;

3) Adding:

```
html, body{width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

4) I also tried to write some js code to set the width of the body on resize, but I am not good at js so it won't helped..

5) Also the font-size change won't helped.

Probably there is a simple solution, but the more I am trying to fix it, the more I get confused, so I hope someone will help me.

I am quite new here, so please for a little more patience for me :).

Here is the body css:

```
body{
background-image: url(gwiazdy.png) !important;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #000;
width: 100% !important;
font-size: 20px !important;
padding: 2% 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
font-family: 'Bellefair', serif !important;
color: #ccc !important;
min-width: 329px !important;}


@media screen and (max-width: 752px) {
.content{
    width: 100% !important;
}
body{
    padding: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 15 !important;
}
}
```

if it's not enaugh, you can [click here](http://janek.ovh) and see my layout, also see the whole css and html.

Comment: you have one element that is larged that the body

Comment: Post the HTML that's relative this question as well

Comment: Its your `.about_text`

Comment: Wow, now it works.. Thanks for Your quick answer :)

Comment: your html markup is incorrect, you can't have `doctype` inside `body`

Comment: On my computer the doctype is on the top of the whole code, so I don't know why when I check the code on a browsher it appears inside the body..

Comment: Incidentally, `doctype` needs a leading exclamation point. See [Recommended Doctype Declarations](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  .title{ 
  text-align: center
  }
  
  .about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .about > div {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  
  .about img {
width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>
      About
     </h2>
   </div>
   
  <div>
    Masz dużo na głowie i nigdy nie masz czasu na szukanie swoich przepisów? Zarejestruj się i trzymaj wszystkie swoje przepisy w jednym miejscu!
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <div>
      <img src="//www.placehold.it/300x300?text=About">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="//www.placehold.it/300x300?text=About">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="//www.placehold.it/300x300?text=About">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

This issue is caused by .about_text elements. The way you coded that section is not correct. You have a `display: flex` set to your .home div, and by default flex has property `flex-direction: row`. However, you are trying to display your elements under the .home div as a column by adding a `width: 100%` to the elements. Use `flex-direction: column` instead and add a new div and place all .about_text elements in that div and add a property of `flex-direction: row` to that div.

Comment: Ok, it works, but now I have a problem with the main issue again.. Probably one element is larger than the parent. And one more time I have no idea which one..

Comment: Remove display: inline-block from the following code.

.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}